# Retrieve form's "name" attribute in Javascript whereas an input exists with name "name"

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, attributes

I have something like this HTML structure :

```
   <form name="myvalue" id="hello">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
    </form>
```

I'd like to retrieve the form's name attribute in Javascript, with a cross browser solution.

Obviously,

```
document.getElementById("hello").name
```

won't work because it will return the corresponding input object.

Under chrome, following code works, but I didn't succeeded to find the equivalent for Internet Explorer 8

```
document.getElementById("hello").getAttribute("name")
```

Thanks in advance !

Frédéric

Comment: So, the question is, which name attribute you are trying to get? The one for the form? Or the one for the text input?

Comment: Purpose it to retrieve the "myvalue" form's name attribute value

Comment: Interesting, getAttribute works for me across all browsers. I tried document.getElementById('tsf').getAttribute('name') on google.com and it returned the form's name (f). I thought it may be related to quirks/standards mode, but it worked with all combinations of browser and document modes. Can you post the full html, including the doctype definition?

Comment: What is your OS ? (I'm under windows 7)

Comment: I'm using XP, and I just tired it under my Windows 7 and it was fine. Did you try running the line I gave you from google.com. I'm mentioning this because I ran across problems with using the attributes collection and set/getAttribute worked for me without the need for a wrapper function to normalize across browsers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this oughtta work

```
document.getElementById("hello").attributes["name"].value;
```

tests ok in IE8, which is all I have. you might have to do some browser checking and pick your approach as needed.

edits: actually, your example works fine for me in IE8 too. but not ie7.

Comment: ooh neat, didn't realize `attributes` had named properties.

Comment: I'll try this on IE 7 though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getFormName (formElement) {
  if (!formElement) return;
  var a=formElement.attributes;
  for (var i=a.length; i--;) {
    if (a[i].name=='name') return a[i].value;
  }
}
```

Not sure if it will work in IE. Should work everywhere else.