# Get form action with button named action

Tags: javascript, html, forms

## Background

Using VanillaJS to obtain an HTML form's `action` attribute value.

## Code

Here is the code and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9b0n1f1L/1/):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function init() {
      alert( document.forms['form-load'].action );
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
  <form name="form-load" id="form-load" action="http://google.com/q">
    <input name="query" id="query" type="text" />
    <button id="button-load" type="submit" name="action" value="load">Load</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## Problem

The dialog shows `[object HTMLButtonElement]` where `http://google.com/q` was expected (using Firefox 32).

## Question

How can the form's `action` attribute value be retrieved?

## Update

The following question might be relevant:

- [Retrieve form's "name" attribute in Javascript whereas an input exists with name "name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937888/retrieve-forms-name-attribute-in-javascript-whereas-an-input-exists-with-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad idea to give form elements names that conflict with standard form property or method names.  For example, avoid giving elements the following names: `submit`, `method`, `action`, `reset`.

If you must, get the attribute value using the `.getAttribute()` method instead:

```
function init() {
  alert( document.forms['form-load'].getAttribute("action") );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad practice to name an attribute `name` with "name". Why not use `id` instead?

```
function init() {
    alert( "By ID:" document.getElementById('form-load').getAttribute('action') );
}
```